# JUnit and Spring configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-webflow

I'm trying to configure JUnit to work with Spring, but I cannot.

I create a test class this way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/web-application-config.xml"})
public class MyControllerToTest {
        @Autowired
    private MyController ctr;

    @Test
    ....
}
```

In classpath, I inserted src/main/resources, where the web-application-config.xml is located. Here its content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Scans for application @Components to deploy -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.infoone.mycontrollerpackage"/>

<!-- Imports the configurations of the different infrastructure systems of the application -->
<import resource="webflow-config.xml" />
<import resource="webmvc-config.xml" />
<import resource="data-access-config.xml" />
<import resource="repository-config.xml" />
<import resource="security-config.xml" />
```

When I run as JUnit the MyControllerToTest class, I get the following:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
[org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6419fa] to prepare test instance [com.infoone.myapp.MyControllerToTest@10036f2]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'flowRegistry' while setting bean property 'flowDefinitionLocator'; nested exception is         org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An I/O Exception occurred resolving the flow location pattern '/**/*-flow.xml'
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An I/O Exception occurred resolving the flow location pattern '/**/*-flow.xml'
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An I/O Exception occurred resolving the flow location pattern '/**/*-flow.xml'
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/flows/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist[/code]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is that the `WEB-IN`F folder is not (so easy) accessible while testing (with maven), because it is in an other location while testing.

I mean:

- when you run the tests, you run the compiled classes in folder: `<project>/target/test-classes` and the `WEB-INF` folder is located in `<project>/target`
- when you run the application the web-inf located in `<war>/WEB-INF` while your classes resists in `<war>/WEB-INF/classes`

What I want to say, the relative path to the resource in `WEB-INF` folder is different between test and application.

Anyway there is a spring project called [spring-test-mvc](http://rossenstoyanchev.org/blog/2012/09/25/second-milestone-of-spring-test-mvc/), maybe you can use it or use some ideas you find in there code.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Would you suggest to move flows out of WEB-INF? I could move them to src/main/resources, but, in that case, I'm not sure how to refer them from my web pages...

Comment: @Manu: the content of `src/main/resources` is merged into the classpath root of your application while building the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `file:src` inside `@ContextConfiguration` and add `@WebAppConfiguration` annotation. So the the test class should look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src:/path.../web-application-config.xml"})
public class MyControllerToTest {
        @Autowired
    private MyController ctr;

    @Test
    ....
}
```